# How do i extract a string between two straight pipes '||' in RazorSQL

Tags: razorsql

I am trying to extract a string from a column in `RazorSQL`.

The strings will vary in characters but they are all in between straight pipes.

```
Ex. 
Data Analysis | Campaign Reports | Other || Account_Name || Account_General_Store
```

In this case, I only want `'Account_Name'`.

Comment: Caseys_General_StoreCasey is also between double pipes.  Wouldn't you want that selected as well?

Comment: No just the first Casey